# pytest How to mock s3fs.S3FileSystem open file

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-s3fs

I am trying to mockup the call to open a file in a S3 bucket. The code that I have is:

```
# mymodule.py
import s3fs
#...
def __init__(self):
    self.s3_filesystem = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, key=s3_key,
                                           secret=s3_secret)
#...
def mymethod(self):
    with self.s3_filesystem.open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
        file_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

The mock that I have in pytest is:

```
import pytest

def test(mocker)                                       
    mocker.patch('mypackage.mymodule.s3fs.S3FileSystem.open',
                 return_value=open)
```

But at run the test I get the error:

```
>       with self.s3_filesystem.open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
E       AttributeError: __enter__
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I found the solution instead of use return_value=open, by using side_effect=open. mocker.patch('mypackage.mymodule.s3fs.S3FileSystem.open', side_effect=open)  see https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2014/04/10/using-the-python-mock-library-to-fake-regular-functions-during-tests/

Answer (score 3):

***Disclaimer***: All credits to my answer are due to the OP [Juan Fernando Jaramillo Botero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882969/juan-fernando-jaramillo-botero?tab=profile) and his comment to his own question, above. I am posting an answer here, because it appears that the OP does not have at least 15 reputation points at the moment - and thus, can't answer his own question, as indicated [in this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). *Please, if this is not the case, I encourage the OP to add his answer - and accept it - because it helped me a lot!*

---

I was having the same problem, where I had to mock two methods from `s3fs.S3FileSystem`: `open` (as OP), and also `ls`, in a `pytest` suite of tests.

By using the decorator `patch`, and its argument `side_effect`, all calls for `s3fs.S3FileSystem.open` and `s3fs.S3FileSystem.ls`  during tests are properly replaced by `open` and `os.listdir`, respectively, which in my case was the desired effect.

Simplified situation:

### my_module.py

```
import s3fs


class Operation():
    def compile_files(self, fs, input_bucket):
        files = fs.ls(input_bucket)

        return files

    def copy_files(self, fs, files, input_bucket, output_bucket):
        for file in files:
            with fs.open(f'{input_bucket}/{file}', 'rb') as source:
                with fs.open(f'{output_bucket}/{file}', 'wb') as destination:
                    destination.write(source.read())

    def transform(self, input_bucket, output_bucket):
        fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

        files = self.compile_files(fs, input_bucket)

        self.copy_files(fs, files, input_bucket, output_bucket)
```

### my_module_test.py

```
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_module import Operation


@patch('s3fs.S3FileSystem.open', side_effect=open)
@patch('s3fs.S3FileSystem.ls', side_effect=os.listdir)
def test_my_module(mock_s3fs_ls, mock_s3fs_open):
    input_bucket = 'test/fixtures/files'
    output_bucket = 'test/fixtures/tmp_output'
    os.mkdir(output_bucket)

    Operation().transform(input_bucket, output_bucket)

    # Proceed to assert everything went as expected...
```

Note that the test file does not import `pytest`, but it is fully compatible and can be run within a `pytest` test suite.